# How do I right-align text in the date section of the GNOME panel?

Tags: fedora, gnome, gnome-panel

I am currently using GNOME 45 with the extension Panel Date Format. I have a multiline time/date box that is aligned to the right of my panel. The text on the top line is shorter than the text in the bottom line, and is aligned at the left edge of the date box. I want to align text to the right, so the text is anchored to the right side of the screen and doesn't look weird. [image: GNOME Panel right side]